# BottomSheetDialogFragment shows along with android bottom nav icons

Tags: android, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I am working on BottomSheetDialogFragment. When it shows it shows along with the android bottom navigation icons. How can I remove that. I tried the below code but didn't work.

````
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)```
````